# Formatting date in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I am working with ExtJS and want to use Ext.Date.format(value,format). I have date as 2014/03/05. How can I convert this to the date object so that it can be passed as 'value' argument to the format() function?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
var dt = new Date('2014/03/05');
```

And you do this to format your date `Ext.Date.format(dt,'d-m-Y');` or whatever format you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can parses date:

```
var dt = Ext.Date.parse("2014/03/05", "Y/m/d");
```

Then you can format it another format:

```
var td = Ext.Date.format(dt,'d-m-Y');
```